# Beans can't implement List?

Tags: java, list, user-interface, netbeans, javabeans

I have two classes that are identical in every way but one; the first implements `List<RuleSet>` while the second doesn't. They have all the same members and methods. When I try to build a GUI using Netbeans' GUI builder, I cannot bind to properties in the list, whereas I can in the other.

Is there something that prevents me from having a class implement a `List` interface and using it as a Bean as well? I can work around it this time, but it is going to require changes in my design I didn't expect.

A concrete example to make things clearer:

- `PatternSet_I` implements `List`
- `PatternSet_J` doesn't implement `List`
- I **can't** bind to properties in instances of `PatternSet_I`
- I **can** bind to properties in instances of `PatternSet_J`

I'll add code below:

**PatternSet_I** implements `List<RuleSet>`

```
package dvrminer.pattern;

import dvrminer.rule.RuleSet;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class PatternSet_I implements List<RuleSet> {

    public static final String PROP_STRING = "string";

    private Pattern pattern;
    private final List<RuleSet> ruleSets;
    private final transient PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport
            = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public PatternSet_I() {
        ruleSets = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    public void setPattern(Pattern pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

//    @Override
    public int size() {
        return ruleSets.size();
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return ruleSets.isEmpty();
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.contains(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public Iterator<RuleSet> iterator() {
        return ruleSets.iterator();
    }

//    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return ruleSets.toArray();
    }

//    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return ruleSets.toArray(a);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean add(RuleSet e) {
        return ruleSets.add(e);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.remove(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return ruleSets.containsAll(c);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends RuleSet> c) {
        return ruleSets.addAll(c);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends RuleSet> c) {
        return ruleSets.addAll(index, c);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return ruleSets.removeAll(c);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return ruleSets.retainAll(c);
    }

//    @Override
    public void clear() {
        ruleSets.clear();
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.equals(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ruleSets.hashCode();
    }

//    @Override
    public RuleSet get(int index) {
        return ruleSets.get(index);
    }

//    @Override
    public RuleSet set(int index, RuleSet element) {
        return ruleSets.set(index, element);
    }

//    @Override
    public void add(int index, RuleSet element) {
        ruleSets.add(index, element);
    }

//    @Override
    public RuleSet remove(int index) {
        return ruleSets.remove(index);
    }

//    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.indexOf(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public ListIterator<RuleSet> listIterator() {
        return ruleSets.listIterator();
    }

//    @Override
    public ListIterator<RuleSet> listIterator(int index) {
        return ruleSets.listIterator(index);
    }

//    @Override
    public List<RuleSet> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return ruleSets.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

**PatternSet_J** doesn't implement `List<RuleSet>`, though otherwise identical.

```
package dvrminer.pattern;

import dvrminer.rule.RuleSet;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class PatternSet_J {

    public static final String PROP_STRING = "string";

    private Pattern pattern;
    private final List<RuleSet> ruleSets;
    private final transient PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport
            = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public PatternSet_J() {
        ruleSets = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    public void setPattern(Pattern pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

//    @Override
    public int size() {
        return ruleSets.size();
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return ruleSets.isEmpty();
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.contains(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public Iterator<RuleSet> iterator() {
        return ruleSets.iterator();
    }

//    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return ruleSets.toArray();
    }

//    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return ruleSets.toArray(a);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean add(RuleSet e) {
        return ruleSets.add(e);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.remove(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return ruleSets.containsAll(c);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends RuleSet> c) {
        return ruleSets.addAll(c);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends RuleSet> c) {
        return ruleSets.addAll(index, c);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return ruleSets.removeAll(c);
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return ruleSets.retainAll(c);
    }

//    @Override
    public void clear() {
        ruleSets.clear();
    }

//    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.equals(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ruleSets.hashCode();
    }

//    @Override
    public RuleSet get(int index) {
        return ruleSets.get(index);
    }

//    @Override
    public RuleSet set(int index, RuleSet element) {
        return ruleSets.set(index, element);
    }

//    @Override
    public void add(int index, RuleSet element) {
        ruleSets.add(index, element);
    }

//    @Override
    public RuleSet remove(int index) {
        return ruleSets.remove(index);
    }

//    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.indexOf(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return ruleSets.lastIndexOf(o);
    }

//    @Override
    public ListIterator<RuleSet> listIterator() {
        return ruleSets.listIterator();
    }

//    @Override
    public ListIterator<RuleSet> listIterator(int index) {
        return ruleSets.listIterator(index);
    }

//    @Override
    public List<RuleSet> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return ruleSets.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Add PropertyChangeListener.
     *
     * @param listener
     */
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Remove PropertyChangeListener.
     *
     * @param listener
     */
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

}
```

**Test** is a form built in NetBeans 8. It has a `PatternSet_I` and a `PatternSet_J` as well as a `JTextArea` called `textArea`. I can bind `textArea` to `patternSet_J1.pattern.name` but not to `patternSet_I1.pattern.name`. The only difference is that `patternSet_I1.pattern.name` implements `List<RuleSet>`.

```
package dvrminer.pattern;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JPanel {


    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        patternSet_I1 = new dvrminer.pattern.PatternSet_I();
        patternSet_J1 = new dvrminer.pattern.PatternSet_J();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        textArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        textArea.setColumns(20);
        textArea.setRows(5);

        org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, patternSet_J1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${pattern.name}"), textArea, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(textArea);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(0, 0, 0))
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private dvrminer.pattern.PatternSet_I patternSet_I1;
    private dvrminer.pattern.PatternSet_J patternSet_J1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea textArea;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: `I can bind textArea to patternSet_J1.pattern.name but not to patternSet_I1.pattern.name. The only difference is that the former implements List<RuleSet>` - Slightly confused as from the code, it is PatternSet_I that implements `List`. Could you correct it so there is no confusion about which class won't bind.

Comment: @DanTemple Sorry, I can't see the mistake. I can't bind to `patternSet_I1.pattern.name`. I can bind to `patternSet_J1.pattern.name`. `patternSet_I1.pattern.name` implements `List`. I think that is what I've already written, isn't it?

Comment: `I can bind textArea to patternSet_J1.pattern.name but not to patternSet_I1.pattern.name. The only difference is that the former implements List<RuleSet>` patternSet_J1.pattern.name is the former in that statement, but it doesn't implement `List`. sounds like you just want to swap former for latter.

Comment: Ah yes. I'll fix it when I can.